# How can I get user if i have auth_token

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I use `"gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'"` and I need to get current_user with some auth_token, but method `"User.find_by_authentication_token"` is deleted. What method can i use instead or just how can i get current user.I use json api.

Comment: @SantoshSharma ty man. It's really help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
User.find_by(authentication_token: "abcd1234")
```

That is not provided by Devise, but Rails (more specifically ActiveRecord). Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by).

The dynamic `find_by_attribute_name` methods were removed from ActiveRecord.